# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'double' Issue

Tags: c#, forms

```
    private void updateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //custID.Text = customers[id].ID.ToString();
        customers[id].Name = custName.Text.ToString();
        customers[id].Suburb = custSuburb.Text.ToString();
        customers[id].Balance = custBal.Text;
        customers[id].Year_used = custYear.Text;
    }

}


public class Customer
{
    protected string id;
    protected string name;
    protected string suburb;
    protected double balance;
    protected double year_used;

    public string ID
    {
        get { return id; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { value = name; }
    }

    public string Suburb
    {
        get { return suburb; }
        set { value = suburb; }
    }

    public double Balance
    {
        get { return balance; }
        set { value = balance; }
    }

    public double Year_used
    {
        get { return year_used; }
        set { value = year_used; }
    }


    public Customer(string id, string name, string suburb, double balance, double year_used)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.suburb = suburb;
        this.balance = balance;
        this.year_used = year_used;
    }

}
```

Seems that i get this error when i try run the code?? what seems to be the issue i changed everything that had int to double.

As well as:

```
        customers[id].Balance = custBal.Text;
        customers[id].Year_used = custYear.Text;
```

What would be the proper code for the custBal. and custYear. to make it display on my form? any ideas?

Comment: You can get rid of the .ToString() on the ID, Name and Suburb assignments too. You're assigning a string (.Text), to a string property. Also have a think about validation - if it's impossible to submit a form without a valid balance and year, then it's fine. But otherwise have a look at [double.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your user is entering a balance and is typing text, so how do you know the text can be represented by a number?  C# will not let you convert a string to a double implicitely because there is no unique way to do that without make substantial assumptions about the string and implicit conversions should never throw an exception (Framework Design Guidelines), so it is best to not offer implicit conversion at all.

For example, since it is a balance, what if the user types "(100.25)" or "-100.25" or "-$100.25" or "-€100,25" or "negative one hundred and twenty-five cents"  All of those are valid strings, so how would you convert them to a double?

The answer is that there is not one correct answer: you can map strings to double in any way that makes sense to you.  You could, of course, write your own function of the form `Func<String, double>` but there are functions provided by the .Net framework that implement the most common and intuitive conversions.

Others have posted `double.Parse` and `double.TryParse` so I want to add to make sure also to look into `NumberStyles` and `IFormatProvider` if necessary.

Comment: Cheers..yeah thanks for the post..yeah nah i knew that string cannot be converted to a double..wasn't thinking very much haha thanks tho!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you know they contain a properly formatted number, what you want is to parse the numeric value contained in each of your strings and assign it to a double type variable (which involves transforming a representation of your number as a string into another of different binary content: a double), not cast it (which doesn't). Try:

```
customers[id].Balance = Double.Parse(custBal.Text);
customers[id].Year_used =  Double.Parse(custYear.Text);
```

Or, if you want to test the parsing's success against a returned boolean instead of doing exception handling to test for a FormatException, you can use TryParse instead:

```
if (!Double.TryParse(custBal.Text, customers[id].Balance))
   Console.WriteLine("Parse Error on custBal.Text");
if (!Double.TryParse(custYear.Text, customers[id].Year_used))
   Console.WriteLine("Parse Error on custYear.Text");
```

More info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ebt447%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx

Comment: Thanks! with the same code it doesn't seem to update any changes when i change information on the forms when i run the program when i click on the update button and click on next changes don't seem to change on my form..any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Double.TryParse()` to convert your string to a Double.You cannot save a string on a Double Datatype and there is no implicit conversion available in c# to do that

```
Double result;
Double.TryParse(custBal.Text,out result);
```

Comment: double to try parse takes two parameters

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign `string` to a `double` directly. You need to parse strings to assign them to doubles, like this:

```
customers[id].Balance = double.Parse(custBal.Text);
customers[id].Year_used = double.Parse(custYear.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to convert 'String' to 'Double' is by using TryParse, as shown below:

```
int result;

if (double.TryParse(custBal.Text, out result))
    customers[id].Balance = result;
if (double.TryParse(custYear.Text, out result))
    customers[id].Year_used = result;
```