# cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'double'

Tags: c#

Hi guys I am trying to use set a text box to only accept double data types as the type of input to be accepted for product price but im getting the following error: `cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'double'`. Can anyone point in me in the right direction please?

`((Employee)o).ProdPrice =  this.textProdName.Text;`

I am getting the eror under `this.textProdName.Text`.

Comment: Search for the error message. After reading some similar issues, what is the suspected problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768625/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-string-to-double-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer TryParse, because if the string can't be parsed, I can decide on what value to return, in the sample below I used Doube.NaN.

```
Double val;

((Employee)o).ProdPrice = Double.TryParse(this.textProdName.Text, out val)?val:Double.NaN;
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to use set a text box to only accept double data types as the type of input to be accepted for product price

Assuming that you already validate the textbox to only accept double values, you need to convert `this.textProdName.Text` to double

```
((Employee)o).ProdPrice = Convert.ToDouble(this.textProdName.Text);
```

However, in case the textbox can't be converted to double, use `Double.TryParse` as below

```
Double prodPrice = 0;

if (Double.TryParse(this.textProdName.Text, out prodPrice))
{
    ((Employee)o).ProdPrice = prodPrice;
}
else
{
    // do something when textProdName.Text can't be converted to double
}
```

Comment: This is good.  Although it may throw exceptions.  `Double.TryParse` would allow for cleaner handling.

Comment: Actually OP said `i am trying to use set a text box to only accept double data types`, so I guess `textProdName.Text` can be converted to double.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Convert.toDouble` or `Double.Parse`

so like this: `((Employee)o).ProdPrice = Convert.ToDouble(this.textProdName.Text);` or `((Employee)o).ProdPrice = Double.Parse(this.textProdName.Text);`